# Perl handling Keyboard Interrupt

Tags: perl, keyboard, interrupt

I'm trying to code a way that when the user types in CTRL+C, the script will proceed with a few more steps before closing. I know how to do this in Python. The python code would be something like this:

```
try:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Desktop\ODFU '+str(System)+'.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    excelcreate(System)
    login(USER, PASS)
    test()
    time.sleep(2)
    print"Test is complete..."
    logout()
except KeyboardInterrupt: # CTRL+C Terminates script and saves everything and logs out
    print""
    print "Interruption occurred!! Script terminating..."
    workbook.close()
    logout()
```

How can I get somethign exactly like this but with Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define a SIGINT handler:

```
local $SIG{INT} = sub {
    $workbook->close;
    logout();
    exit 130
};
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up declaring $SIG{'INT' } = 'interrupt'; and then declaring the sub function.